# Heroku hangs during login

Tags: heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy my project on Heroku platform and I have already succeeded in this.
But after something happens, Heroku cli doesn't allow me to push the project and process of login looks like

I have already reloaded Heroku cli, but it doesn't work

'''
Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/browser/378fa71d-d5f6-4fec-8e85-f17fc40e
20d7
Logging in... done
Logged in as happiva@yandex.ru

and it isn't working